# ERROR 404 popping up when navigating from my contacts page to my home page

Tags: html, css

I have four pages home, about, projects and contacts, all links work fine except when i navigate from the contacts page back to the home page, ERROR 404 pops up and i have no idea why, here is my webpage to
check it out here,

https://chrisalta94.github.io/Christopher-Personal-Portfolio/index.html

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are linking **Home** to `home.html` instead of to `index.html` at the **Contacts** page.

Use this `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` instead of this `<a href="home.html">Home</a>`